# Error with mysql before insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write a mysql trigger that will only allow 1 of 2 columns to have a value in it. The table looks like this:

`tbl_lesson`

```
lessonID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ==> PRIMARY KEY
studentID int ==> FOREIGN KEY
classID int ==> FOREIGN KEY
```

My trigger looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_lesson
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare counter int DEFAULT 0;
    IF studentID IS NULL AND classID IS NOT NULL THEN
        set counter := counter + 1;
    END IF;
    IF studentID IS NOT NULL AND classID IS NULL THEN
        set counter := counter + 1;
    END IF;
    IF counter != 1 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEST = "Only studentID or classID must be null";
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Currently, whenever I try to input anything to that table (regardless on whether it should be valid or not), this error is returned.

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'studentID' in 'field list'
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: `NEW.studentID`, `NEW.classID`

Comment: Thank you!! It seems like a pretty silly mistake in hindsight...

Comment: Some of the most frustrating ones can be.